# Borel-Cantelli Lemma to prove limsup of Brownian motion is infty

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

> Use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma and reflection principle to show that 
>   $$\limsup_{t\to \infty}B_t=\infty$$

The proof starts by constructing the following events
$$E_i:=\{\inf\{t\ge0:B_t=i\}\lt \infty\}$$.

$$\mathbb P(E_i)=\lim_{t\to \infty} \mathbb P(\max_{s\le t}B_s\ge i)$$
$$=\lim_{t\to \infty} 2\mathbb P(B_t\ge i)$$
$$=\lim_{t\to \infty} 2\mathbb P(B_1\ge \frac{i}{\sqrt t})=1$$

Then later in the proof, it is claimed that $E_i$ are independent for any $i$. I cannot figure out why. Any help?

Then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb P(E_i)=\infty$$
by BC we have the result.

Comment: Try to write $E_i$ in terms of Brownian motion increments...

Comment: If the brownian motion has reached some $i$, it must have reached any $k<=i$, right?

Comment: Trivial events (like the $E_i$) are always independent: $\Bbb P[E_i\cap E_j]=1= 1\cdot 1=\Bbb P[E_i]\cdot\Bbb P[E_j]$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks i see. Can you just copy your comments into answer, so i can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial events (like the $E_i$) are always independent: $\Bbb P[E_i\cap E_j]=1= 1\cdot 1=\Bbb P[E_i]\cdot\Bbb P[E_j]$.

Comment: Why are these events trivial?

Comment: Because they have probability 1.