# Convergence almost surely of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, solution-verification, brownian-motion, almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

If $B_t \sim N(0,t)$ then, intuitively, for any fixed $\varepsilon$,  as $t \to \infty$, the probability that $B_t$ will be observed within the $[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]$ interval should converge to $0$, due to the increasing variance. But since $B_t$ is a continuous rv, I'm not sure how to use Borel-Cantelli Lemma here.

First, if $B_t \sim N(0,t)$, then $Z_t = \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}} \sim N(0,1)$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty}P(|B_t|>\varepsilon) &= \lim_{t \to \infty} P\bigg(\frac{|B_t|}{\sqrt{t}}>\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{t}}\bigg) \\&= \lim_{t \to \infty}P\bigg(Z_t>\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{t}}\bigg) + P\bigg(Z_t<-\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{t}}\bigg) \\&= \lim_{t \to \infty}1- \Phi(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{t}}) + \Phi(-\frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{t}}) \\&= 1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} = 1. 
\end{align}
This, I believe, amounts the proof that $B_t$ diverges in probability, i.e.
$$
\text{plim}_{t \to \infty}B_t = \pm\infty
$$
But I'm not sure how to extend it to $\lim_{t \to \infty} P(\limsup B_t=\infty)=1$. I understand that $\mathbf{E}[B_{t+h}B_t]=t \neq 0$, so $B_t$ are not independent, hence only Borel-Cantelli Lemma-I will work here, so I somehow need to show that there exists a sequence of events $I_t = \{t:|B_t|<\varepsilon\}$, and then prove the sum converges, but not sure how to do it. Do I need to split the timeline into disjoint intervals?

I know this question was asked before, but I'm interested if the logic above is correct and can be extended to the proof if convergence a.s.

Comment: I suppose $P(\limsup B_t)=\infty$ should be $P(\limsup B_t=\infty) = 1$?  And is that all you're ultimately trying to show?

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes I suppose so. Is this not a good question?

Comment: The issue is whether that is your question, not whether it is a good question.  At the moment, your real question is hidden in the middle of the body of text and only mentioned once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$, there is $T$ large enough that for any $t \geq T$, $P(|B_t| \leq \varepsilon) < \delta$. Presumably, you want to show that
$$P(\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty} B_t = \infty) = 1,$$
not $P(\dots) = \infty$, as pointed out in a comment. Moreover, the statement  $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} B_t = \pm\infty$ is not true, because almost surely $B = \{B_t, t\geq0\}$ crosses $0$ infinitely often, and the limit does not exist.

1. If you don't need to use Borel-Cantelli, the Law of Iterated Logarithm will give you $P(\limsup_t B_t = \infty) = 1$ directly.
2. If you don't want to use the hammer of LIL but don't need to directly use Borel-Cantelli, the usual argument is the same as that for a random walk on the integers using a 0-1 law. First, note that, for any $0<A<\infty$,
   $$\{ \limsup_n B_n \leq A\} \subset \liminf_n \{B_n \leq A\} = \cup_{m=1}^\infty \cap_{n=m}^\infty \{B_n \leq A\}.$$
   The right-hand side is the liminf of sets, which means that the sequence of events occurs "all but finitely many times". Indeed,  if $\omega \in\{\limsup_n B_n(\omega) \leq A\}$ then certainly there is an $m<\infty$ large enough that for all $n \geq m$, $\omega \in \{B_n \leq A\}$. You've already shown that $P(B_n \leq A) < \delta < 1$ for all $n$, and since for any sequence of sets $E_n$,
   $$P(\liminf_n E_n) \leq \liminf_n P(E_n),$$
   you also have $P(\limsup_n B_n \leq A) \leq \delta < 1$. Since $\{\limsup_n B_n \leq A\}$ is a tail event, the probability is $0$. Since $0 < A< \infty$ is arbitrary, the result follows.
3. If you insist on using Borel-Cantelli, the only argument I could think of uses some form of strong Markov property, in order to use independent events, or perhaps use a stronger (the strongest) version of Borel-Cantelli. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458350/borel-cantelli-lemma-to-prove-limsup-of-brownian-motion-is-infty?rq=1) is an argument using the reflection principle.

Comment: What is $B_n$, a subset of $B_t$ taken at integer time units? Also, what is $\{ \limsup B_n<A\}$, a set of limit suprema?

Comment: Yes, $B_t$ at $t=n$. Regarding your second question, it is the event $\{\omega : f(\omega) < A\}$, where $f(\omega) = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} B_n(\omega)$. You have not yet corrected your mistake in your original post so I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't fully understand what $B_t$ actually is, since an rv $N(0, t)$ means that that it's unlikely to take values in the interval $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ due to the diverging variance. The difference between this and a stochastic process is that $B_t$ will take an infinite number of values in this interval, but, roughly speaking, its peaks will keep growing larger (both negative and positive). Combining it with your answer, $P(\limsup A_n)=1$, where $A_n = B_t \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$

Comment: We should avoid extended discussions in comments, but I'm still not sure what your question is. Yes, $P(\limsup_n A_n) = 1$, where $A_n = \{B_n \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\}$, but that's not what my answer was about. If you're confused about something related to Brownian motion, perhaps it's better to start a new question about that. Edit: last thing, note that $\limsup_n B_n$ is defined *exactly* as for a sequence of numbers, one sequence for each fixed $\omega$. There is a sequence of real numbers $\{B_n(\omega)\}_{n \geq 1} \subset \mathbb{R}$ for each fixed $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks. Again, I confused $\limsup$ for events, which is an event and $\limsup$ for rvs, which is a number or infinity. The book I use (Rosenthal's Advanced Probability) doesn't discuss this step. I should really go back to the definiton of $B_t$ to better understand it

Comment: In 2. you used the fact that $\limsup$ is a tail event, which requires events to be independent. How do we know that $\{B_n<A\}$ are independent?

Comment: @Alex Note that $B_n = \sum_{i=1}^n B_i - B_{i-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$. While $\{ \limsup_n B_n/n < A\}$ belongs to the tail generated by $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$, $\{\limsup_n B_n < A\}$ does not. However, the event $\{\limsup_n B_n < A\}$ _does_ belong to the exchangeable $\sigma$-algebra generated by the (i.i.d.) $X_i$, and so the Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law applies to establish $P(\{\limsup_n B_n < A\}) = 0$ or $1$.

Comment: Ok so $B_n$ are not independent then?

Comment: @Alex I think that is a question you need to answer for yourself.